# Weird postgres Errors after running db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

When I run `rails db:create`, I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.18.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "username"=>"postgres", "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>5433, "url"=>nil, "database"=>"mydatabase"}
```

I'm not sure how to fix it. I've modified my `pg_hba.conf` file to include the following line.

```
host    postgres             postgres             172.18.0.1/32            md5
```

But I'm still getting that error.

Comment: Did you reload Postgres after changing the configuration file?

Comment: Yes, I did.

I can also connect to `psql -d template1` properly.

Comment: The format is `host database user address auth-method`, so your rule is only for the postgres database. Try `host all all 172.18.0.1/32 md5`

Comment: @Andomar I have that but I'm still getting this error

Comment: Examine the Postgres logs?  Location depends on your distribution, but look for a directory called `pg_log`

Comment: Interestingly, nothing happens to the logs when this error occurs.

Comment: I created a blank Rails application running Postgres and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: What's your OS, and how have you installed postgres?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm on OSX. I used brew to install postgres

Comment: Actually it seems like it did end up working with the blank Rails application